# Unsure how to unit test interface in Kotlin with chained block

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I'm working with Kotlin (for Android), along with jUnit and Koin.

I have an interface to consume that looks like this:

```
interface MyInterface {  
    fun vehicle(id: String, block: VehicleInterface.() -> Unit) 
}

interface VehicleInterface {   
    fun requestVersion()
}
```

The code that calls this method looks like this:

```
import com.domain.protocol.thelibrary.sdk.MyInterface

// The below is injected via Koin
class SomeClass(private val myInterface: MyInterface) {    
    fun functionIWantToUnitTest(id: String) {
        myInterface.vehicle(id) {
            requestVersion()
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to unit test that when I call `functionIWantToUnitTest` and pass in the id "1" then myInterface.vehicle is called with id "1" and I'd also like to verify that requestVersion is then called.

I wrote a unit test as such:

```
    @Test
    fun `Ensure functionIWantToUnitTest calls requestVersion with the correct id`() {
    every { myInterface.vehicle("1", any()) } returns Unit
    someClass.functionIWantToUnitTest("1")

    verifySequence {
        myInterface.vehicle("1") {
            requestVersion()
        }
    }
}
```

This fails as such:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: 
MyInterface(myInterface#1).vehicle(eq(1), eq(lambda {}))). Only one matching call to 
MyInterface(myInterface#1)/vehicle(String, Function1) happened, but arguments are not 
matching:
[0]: argument: 1, matcher: eq(1), result: +
[1]: argument: lambda {}, matcher: eq(lambda {}), result: -
```

Can anyone please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong...

Any help gratefully accepted.